# Employee Wage Deduction On Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to deduct wage depending upon employee late attendance count. So my condition is: if an employee continuously comes late 3 days (Except friday and saturday - Weekly holidays), then one day salary will be deducted. The sample is as follows and this is what I have now with the given query:

```
Name  PunchDate             Attendance   PerDaySal          Status    
John  2017-05-12 00:00:00.000   W        461.538461538462   Weekly
John  2017-05-13 00:00:00.000   W        461.538461538462   Weekly
John  2017-05-14 09:00:00.000   P        461.538461538462   On Time
John  2017-05-15 09:16:00.000   P        461.538461538462   Late
John  2017-05-16 09:18:00.000   P        461.538461538462   Late
John  2017-05-17 09:20:00.000   P        0                  Late -- On 3rd consecutive day
John  2017-05-18 09:26:00.000   P        461.538461538462   Late
John  2017-05-19 00:00:00.000   W        461.538461538462   Weekly
John  2017-05-20 00:00:00.000   W        461.538461538462   Weekly
John  2017-05-21 09:18:00.000   P        461.538461538462   Late
John  2017-05-22 09:28:00.000   P        0                  Late -- On the next 3rd consecutive day (Possibly 6th)           
John  2017-05-23 09:28:00.000   P        461.538461538462   Late
```

In the above, when it comes to attendance late count on the third consecutive day, then the deduction takes place. Again, let me remind, this must be excluded friday and saturday. I am able to show the late count and weekly holidays but not sure how would I proceed with the deduction. I am planning to make a table 'Deduction' for the deduction purpose to store the days as follows if I am not mistaken:

```
ID    Days  
1     3 ---- On 3rd late count, PerDaySal 0
2     6 ---- On 6th late count, PerDaySal 0 and so on
```

But for specific month (Even per 3 days), how would the logic be validated? I tried a silly one (Never going a solution though):

```
SELECT k.NAME AS Employee, m.PunchDate,

(CASE WHEN o.WeekName = 'Friday' OR o.WeekName = 'Saturday' THEN 'W' ELSE m.Status END) 
AS Attendance,

(CASE WHEN o.WeekName = 'Friday' OR o.WeekName = 'Saturday' THEN 0 ELSE (k.SALARY / 26) END) 
AS PerDaySal,

(CASE WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), m.PunchDate, 108) > '09:15:00' THEN 'Late'  
 WHEN CONVERT(CHAR(8), m.PunchDate, 108) >= '09:00:00' AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), m.PunchDate, 108) <= '09:15:00' THEN 'On Time'
 WHEN o.WeekName = 'Friday' OR o.WeekName = 'Saturday' AND CONVERT(CHAR(8), m.PunchDate, 108) <= '00:00:00' THEN 'Weekly' END) AS Status

--The silly one - (CASE WHEN COUNT(CONVERT(CHAR(8), m.PunchDate, 108) > '09:15:00') > 3 THEN 0 ELSE (k.SALARY / 26) END) AS PerDaySal

FROM @Attendances m INNER JOIN @Employee k ON k.ID = m.EmpId 
LEFT JOIN @Weekly o ON o.WeekDate = m.PunchDate
GROUP BY k.NAME, m.PunchDate, m.Status, k.Salary, o.WeekName
```

Here are the table structures with sample data:

```
declare @Attendances table (Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,EmpId int,PunchDate datetime,Status nvarchar(4));
insert into @Attendances([EmpId],[PunchDate],[Status]) values
 (2,cast(0x0000A77200000000 as datetime),N'A')
,(2,cast(0x0000A77100000000 as datetime),N'A')
,(2,cast(0x0000A776009A5BA0 as datetime),N'P')
,(2,cast(0x0000A775009450C0 as datetime),N'P')
,(2,cast(0x0000A77400982920 as datetime),N'P')
,(2,cast(0x0000A773009450C0 as datetime),N'P');

declare @Employee table (ID int not null primary key,NAME nvarchar(50),ADDRESS nvarchar(max),SALARY float);
insert @Employee([ID], [NAME], [ADDRESS], [SALARY]) values
 (1, N'John', N'Germany', 12000)
,(2, N'Jack', N'France', 14000);

declare @Weekly table (WeekID int not null primary key,WeekNAME nvarchar(20),WeekDate datetime,Status nvarchar(10));
insert @Weekly([WeekID], [WeekName], [WeekDate], [Status]) values
 (1, N'Friday', CAST(0x0000A77100000000 AS DateTime), N'W')
,(2, N'Saturday', CAST(0x0000A77200000000 AS DateTime), N'W');
```

Comment: Just a note to thank you for the test data script!  Though are the `Employee` and `Weekly` tables supposed to be empty?

Comment: Why is `PerDaySal` 0 on `2017-05-22` if you aren't counting `Late` when it occurs on Saturday `2017-05-20`.

Comment: Welcome @iamdave. Just trying to make it as simple as possible. Looking forward. **Note:** Never mind. Posted the rest of the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for notifying @SqlZim. Now updated and please check.

Comment: Also, how are you defining 'late'?  Your first table has `09:14:00` marked as `Late` but your SQL script is looking for `PunchDate` times after `09:15:00`.

Comment: Edited again. The in time is between 9:00:00 and 9:15:00.

Comment: And surely `PunchDate = 2017-05-21` is the third consecutive day being late as the last day of the previous week was also late?

Comment: That will be for `PunchDate = 2017-05-22`. I should be careful while posting. See now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example table instead of the multiple tables, with a common table expression and window functions with a `case` expression to not count a day as late if it on Friday or Saturday per the question specification at the time of this writing.

```
;with cte as (
select * 
  , rn = row_number() over (partition by Name order by punchDate)
  , DayName = datename(weekday,punchdate)
  , LateDays = (select sum(
    case when datename(weekday,punchdate) not in ('Friday','Saturday') and [Status]='Late'
        then 1 else 0 end
  )
  from t i
  where i.Name = t.Name and i.PunchDate <= t.PunchDate
  )
from t
)
select 
    cte.Name
  , cte.PunchDate
  , cte.DayName
  , cte.Attendance
  , PerDaysSal = case when z.rn is not null then 0 
      else cte.PerDaySal end
  , cte.Status
  , cte.rn
  , cte.LateDays
from cte
  left join (
    select i.Name, rn=min(i.rn)
    from cte i
    where i.LateDays > 0
      and i.LateDays % 3 = 0
    group by Name, LateDays
      ) z
  on cte.Name = z.Name
 and cte.rn = z.rn
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ETOI35350

returns:

```
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------+----+----------+
| Name |      PunchDate      |  DayName  | Attendance |  PerDaysSal   | Status  | rn | LateDays |
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------+----+----------+
| John | 12.05.2017 00:00:00 | Friday    | W          | 461,538461538 | Weekly  |  1 |        0 |
| John | 13.05.2017 00:00:00 | Saturday  | W          | 461,538461538 | Weekly  |  2 |        0 |
| John | 14.05.2017 00:00:00 | Sunday    | P          | 461,538461538 | On Time |  3 |        0 |
| John | 15.05.2017 00:00:00 | Monday    | P          | 461,538461538 | Late    |  4 |        1 |
| John | 16.05.2017 00:00:00 | Tuesday   | P          | 461,538461538 | Late    |  5 |        2 |
| John | 17.05.2017 00:00:00 | Wednesday | P          | 0,000000000   | Late    |  6 |        3 |
| John | 18.05.2017 00:00:00 | Thursday  | P          | 461,538461538 | Late    |  7 |        4 |
| John | 19.05.2017 00:00:00 | Friday    | W          | 461,538461538 | Weekly  |  8 |        4 |
| John | 20.05.2017 00:00:00 | Saturday  | P          | 461,538461538 | Late    |  9 |        4 |
| John | 21.05.2017 00:00:00 | Sunday    | P          | 461,538461538 | On Time | 10 |        4 |
| John | 22.05.2017 00:00:00 | Monday    | P          | 461,000000000 | Late    | 11 |        5 |
| John | 23.05.2017 00:00:00 | Tuesday   | P          | 0,000000000   | Late    | 12 |        6 |
+------+---------------------+-----------+------------+---------------+---------+----+----------+
```

---

Instead of partitioning by `Name`, it should be partitioned by `EmpId` when using the actual tables. You can also use the `id` from Attendance instead of the `row_number()` used to number the rows.

Comment: Never mind @SqlZim. Time is also an important factor here. I am not sure if you handled them here. **Sample:** The in time is between 9:00:00 and 9:15:00 or count late. Got it. It's a working one.

Comment: @AT-2017 Whatever you consider to be late can take the place of `[Status] = 'Late' ` in the query above.

Comment: @AT-2017 All of your revisions to the question and example table are making it harder to follow, but here is an updated demo that calculates the `Late` based on the time and weekday and uses your updated sample table: http://rextester.com/DVF49830

Comment: @AT-2017 My original answer is based on revision 2: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/717b1b83-7a14-4a25-a6b9-fcefe3be1927/view-source -- The difference between that example and your current example is that it calls into question my understanding of your use of the term _consecutive_. In Revision 2, it does not appear to mean that the Late days must be in a row (i.e. _not_ reset by having an On Time day between Late Days), just that they occur. Do any of your question edits change that?

Comment: No. See the updated one now. Though I am having little issue here and unable to run the query in my environment. Is it required to store the data into `t` and then run? **Update:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44029378/employee-wage-deduction-on-condition

Comment: @AT-2017 I didn't see the `sql-server-2008` tag, I have updated the answer to use a subquery instead of `sum() over(partition by ... order by ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the sample query @SqlZim and works perfectly. One more thing - I guess, I've to use temp table to store the data from the query that I earlier used (With the `CASE` statement). I am not that proficient to use temp tables and could you please show me a sample temp table to store those data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144489/discussion-between-sqlzim-and-at-2017).